# Puzzling Polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Can someone explain the reason for the non-polymorphic behavior of this piece of simple C++ code?

```
// src/main.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
public:
    Base() {
        std::cout << "Making Base" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void hello() {
        std::cout << "Hello Base" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {
        std::cout << "Making Derived" << std::endl;
    }
    void  hello() override {
        std::cout << "Hello Derived" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base* bp = new Derived();
    // Making Base
    // Making Derived
    bp->hello();
    // Hello Derived

    Base b = Derived();
    // Making Base
    // Making Derived
    b.hello();
    // Hello Base
}
```

Compile and run:

```
% g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -o obj/main.o -c src/main.cpp
% g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -o app obj/main.o
% ./app
Making Base
Making Derived
Hello Derived
Making Base
Making Derived
Hello Base
```

I would have expected `b.hello()` to generate output `Hello Derived`, or cause a compiler warning/error.

Comment: virtual dispatch requires references or pointers.

Comment: `Base b = Derived();` is object slicing

Comment: and irrespective of that, `b.hello();` would always call `Base::hello`

Comment: I think it is well explained in this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing

Comment: You might find it interesting to add output to the destructors of your classes, e.g. `virtual ~Base() { std::cout << "Destroying Base\n"; }` and `~Derived() { std::cout << "Destroying Derived\n"; }`.